# Getting image to change based on the selected place

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstSegControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondSegControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var msgLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var locationImageView: UIImageView!
    var = curPlace = "Keeneland"

    //This will list all of the cities
    //and all of the places.
    let cities: [String] = [
            "Lexington",
            "Chengdu",
            "Chicago",
            "Hongkong",
        ]
        let places: [[String]] = [
            ["Keeneland", "Arboretum"],
            ["Panda", "Pedestrian Street"],
            ["Millenium", "Skydeck", "Cruise", "Planetarium"],
            ["Disneyland", "Ocean Park", "The Peak"]
        ]
    //This is the action function that allows the two segmented controlls to work alongside eachother.
    @IBAction func locationChoiceIsMade(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        updateSecondSegControl(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }
    @IBAction func labelChoiceIsMade(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        curPlace = sender.titleForSegment(at: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)!
        msgLabel.text = (curPlace)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        firstSegControl.removeAllSegments()
                for i in 0..<cities.count {
                    firstSegControl.insertSegment(withTitle: cities[i], at: i, animated: false)
                }
                firstSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
                updateSecondSegControl(0)
    }
    //This will make the second segmented control update based off of the first ones selection.
    func updateSecondSegControl(_ n: Int) -> Void {
            secondSegControl.removeAllSegments()
            for i in 0..<places[n].count {
                secondSegControl.insertSegment(withTitle: places[n][i], at: i, animated: false)
            }
            secondSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    }
    
}
```

Edit:
I was able to get the labels to start working, correctly changing based on the place selected. Now, I need to get the picture to change based on the selected place. I am going to keep testing some ideas, any help is appreciated!

[Example of the end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbyTi.png)

Comment: You need to explain your problem in detail. No one is going to read your code and find what the actual problem is that you are facing.
Elaborate your problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about your data when you're getting started.

Presumably, you'll either have a database or you'll be pulling the information from a remote server.

You might have a data structure like this:

```
struct Place {
    var placeName: String = ""
    var imgName: String = ""
}

struct City {
    var cityName: String = ""
    var places: [Place] = []
}
```

Then, you'd create a data array:

```
var cities: [City] = []
```

and you'd fill the array:

```
    var somePlace: [Place]!
    var aPlace: Place!
    var aCity: City!
    
    // Lexington
    somePlace = []
    
    aPlace = Place(placeName: "Keeneland", imgName: "KeenelandPicture")
    somePlace.append(aPlace)
    
    aPlace = Place(placeName: "Arboretum", imgName: "ArboretumPicture")
    somePlace.append(aPlace)

    aCity = City(cityName: "Lexington", places: somePlace)

    cities.append(aCity)

    
    // Chengdu
    somePlace = []
    
    aPlace = Place(placeName: "Place 1", imgName: "Place1Picture")
    somePlace.append(aPlace)
    
    aPlace = Place(placeName: "Place 2", imgName: "Place2Picture")
    somePlace.append(aPlace)
    
    aCity = City(cityName: "Chengdu", places: somePlace)
    
    cities.append(aCity)
    
    // and so on
```

Now, to fill your first segmented control:

```
    firstSegControl.removeAllSegments()
    for i in 0..<cities.count {
        let aCity = cities[i]
        firstSegControl.insertSegment(withTitle: aCity.cityName, at: i, animated: false)
    }
```

and to fill your second segmented control:

```
func updateSecondSegControl(_ n: Int) -> Void {
    secondSegControl.removeAllSegments()
    let aCity = cities[n]
    let places = aCity.places
    for i in 0..<places.count {
        let aPlace = places[i]
        secondSegControl.insertSegment(withTitle: aPlace.placeName, at: i, animated: false)
    }
    secondSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
}
```

and to set your image when the second segmented control is changed:

```
    let aCity = cities[firstSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
    let places = aCity.places
    let aPlace = places[secondSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
    if let img = UIImage(named: aPlace.imgName) {
        locationImageView.image = img
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Seeing examples are game changers for me.